# Custom dropdown box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can we write custom dropdown box using javascript,html,css. and also placing backgroung-image for that.

any sample example

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. with **css** it goes like this.

add couple of class to your css page, like this:

```
.cmdUnbelievable
{
    width:200px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    background-color:#0b5925;
    color:#d4d5d4;  
    border:dashed 2px #f2f2f2;
}
.cmdUnbelievable option
{
    color:#f2f2f2;
    border-bottom:solid 0px white;
    border:dashed 2px #f2f2f2;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

then give a class to your select box :

```
    <select class="cmdUnbelievable">
        <option>We are</option>
        <option>the knights</option>
        <option>who say Ni.</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: @kumar mentions setting a background image... FYI if you try to set one on the option elements it won't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a custom dropdown box like element.
You can use a div for this purpose and set the background-image property for that div.
You can add ul as menu items.

But you have to write code for event like mouseclick, mouseover, mouseout, keydown etc